# Serialization problems using @ElementCollection, @CollectionTable and LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, jpa, serialization, jodatime

I'm experiencing some serialization problems in my Java 8 + Spring + Lombok project. These are my classes:

**Operation.java**

```
public classe Operation 
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
private Long id;

@NonNull
@NotEmpty
private String name;

...

@ElementCollection(targetClass = Period.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "operation_period", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "operation_id"))
@OrderBy("start DESC")
private List<Period> periods = new ArrayList<Period>();

}
```

**Period.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Period implements Serializable 
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8749871604855032518L;

@NonNull
@NotNull
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private LocalDate start;

@NonNull
@NotNull
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private LocalDate end;
```

Whenever I try to query my database using JPQL, I got exceptions like this:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303135
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:70)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
```

I can't find what's is wrong with my mapping. 
Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: As a broader question, why are you using manual type annotations instead of Hibernate's `java8` plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your question. In fact, this is a legacy project, coded by other team and already shipped to production a few years ago. I can't tell you for sure why @Type annotations were used (people left the company), but they seem to work across the project. I didn't want to make any big changes unless it's really necessary.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I just upgraded from Spring 4 with Hibernate 5.2, to Spring 5 with Hibernate 5.4 and now I have the same issue. Joda LocalDate works without any issue on the "root" Entity. But on @Embeddable I get `could not deserialize` and `invalid stream header`.